# sql to linq query convert

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I try to convert `SQL` to `LINK` query

I try this

`SQL` query

```
Select name, count(*) from tblVehicles
WHERE MID = 23065 and name<> '' Group By name
```

`LINQ` query

```
var re = (from vehvoila in DB.tblVehicles
             where vehvoila.MID='23065' && vehvoila.name
             group vehvoila by new{vehvoila.name} into g
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.name,
                 cnt=g.Select(t=>t.name).Count()
             });
```

How I use <> in `LINQ` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What could work for you is

```
where vehvoila.MID == "23065" && !(vehvoila.name == null || vehvoila.name == "")
```

or just

```
where vehvoila.MID == "23065" && vehvoila.name != ""
```

`String.IsNullOrEmpty` in not supported in Linq-SQL:

> Method 'Boolean IsNullOrEmpty(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Comment: i try this && !(vehvoila.name == "") and error occur on this '23065' Error Too many characters in character literal

Comment: You're trying to use single quotes for string literals - that's invalid in C#, unlike SQL. Single quotes are for character literals (char). You need double quotes for string literals. See my edited answer

Comment: i try  this vehvoila.MID == "23065" but shows error .. so when i use this this work 

     where vehvoila.MasterID.Equals("23065") && !(vehvoila.VName == "")